# Do ferrous sulfite and aluminum sulfite exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stability

Source: Concise Chemistry-ICSE (Class X)SELINA PUBLISHERS Pg 207

In this book, it is mentioned that ferrous sulfite and aluminum sulfite does not exist. 
I even tried searching these on Google but didn't get any satisfactory results.

Why do these compounds do not exist?[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Atomistry](http://iron.atomistry.com/ferrous_sulphite.html) gives a brief description about iron(II) sulfite:

> Ferrous sulfite, $\ce{FeSO3.3H2O}$, is obtained by dissolving iron in
> aqueous sulfurous acid in the absence of air. Upon concentration the
> salt is deposited as colourless crystals. The reaction is somewhat
> complicated, for no hydrogen gas is liberated during the solution of
> the iron, the nascent hydrogen reducing some of the sulfurous acid
> (or ferrous sulfite) to thiosulfuric acid (or ferrous thiosulfate).
> Thus:
>
> $$\ce{2Fe + 3H2SO3 -> FeSO3 + FeS2O3 + 3H2O}$$
>
> The thiosulfate, being very soluble in water, remains in solution.
>
> Ferrous sulfite also results when solutions of ferrous salts and
> sodium sulfite interact, and when ferrous hydroxide is dissolved in
> aqueous sulfurous acid. In these circumstances a red solution is
> usually obtained, probably because of interaction with dissolved
> oxygen. The colour quickly disappears, however, particularly on
> warming. On concentration, the salt crystallises out.
>
> On passing a current of sulfur dioxide into an aqueous suspension of
> freshly precipitated ferrous sulfide, the latter passes into solution
> and ferrous sulfite is gradually deposited:
>
> $$\ce{FeS + SO2 + H2O -> FeSO3 + H2S}$$
>
> Ferrous sulfite solution readily oxidises in air, yielding a red
> solution. From its colourless solutions alkalies precipitate ferrous
> hydroxide.

---

A chemist named Jacquemart prepared aluminum sulfite by passing a current of sulfur dioxide through a solution of sodium aluminate. The precipitate is collected and dissolved in excess of sulfurous acid. It also eliminates formation of basic aluminum sulfite as sodium bisulfite gets dissolved. Another method of preparing is by heating concentrated solution of sodium sulfide with aluminum sulfate which on cooling, sodium sulfate crystallizes out leaving behind aluminum sulfite.

A new method has also been discovered. When a solution of tetramethylammonium sulfite is added to a solution of aluminum chloride in liquid sulfur dioxide, voluminous amount of aluminum sulfite is formed.

$$\ce{2AlCl3 + 3(Me4N)2SO3 ->[liq. SO2] Al2(SO3)3 \downarrow + 6Me4NCl}$$

If excess of tetramethylammonium sulfite is added, the precipitate redissolves and a complex is formed. It can be fixed by adding thionyl chloride which reprecipitates back

$$\ce{Al2(SO3)3 + 3(Me4N)2SO3 -> 2(Me4N)3Al(SO3)3 }$$
$$\ce{2(Me4N)3Al(SO3)3 + 3SOCl2 -> Al2(SO3)3 \downarrow + 6Me4NCl +6SO2}$$

It is very soluble in water and when heated gives sulfur dioxide and when heated to extended period, a precipitate of $\ce{Al2O3.SO2.4H2O}$ is formed but at redness, it loses all sulfur atoms and gives out pure aluminum oxide.

**Reference**

1. *The Manufacture of Alum and the Sulphates and Other Salts of Alumina and Iron*, Lucien Geschwind Scott, Greenwood & Company, **1901**
2. *Journal of the American Chemical Society*, Volume 5, American Chemical Society, **1883**
3. *Chemistry in Aqueous and Non-aqueous Solvents*, Y. Mido, S. Taguchi
   Discovery Publishing House, **2001**

Answer (score -1):

They don't exist because they are not energetically feasible.
I also think that what is represented at http://iron.atomistry.com/ferrous_sulphite.html is mostly wishful thinking.  Each "reaction" supposedly producing FeSO3 can be represented by an equilibrium which lies farther to the left.

Comment: FeSO3 is fine (if not straightforward). It is Fe2(SO3)3 that doesn't exist.